# SIP servlet FORM authentication

Tags: java, authentication, sip-servlet

I have a java client/server application based on HTTP. Now I want to add some SIP functionality. The server can accept SIP messages from authenticated user only but the authentication is HTTP based.

Is there a way to authorize SIP messages only for user authenticated via HTTP?

Container: mobicents 2 on JBoss 7

PS: I use declarative security so the container must be aware of the user identity.

**UPDATE**

What I need is a sort of authentication tracking system, something like a cookie for sip messages: a token to add in every sip message that inform the container that I'm already authenticated via HTTP.

A way could be to pass a token by means of a custom SIP header than using `@SipApplicationKey` to join the SipApplicationSession. In this case the problem is that I can't generate the key form the HttpSession. besides I'm not sure that join a SipApplicationSession solve the problem since the jsr289 says that a SipApplicationSession can have more than one HttpSession thus, potentially, more than one authenticated user.

Comment: Form authentication for a SIP servlet is no different from form authentication for any other servlet. It's all defined in `web.xml` and the Servlet Specification.

Comment: @EJP: yes but once the user is authenticated via HTTP how can the sip container know if the incoming sip message belongs to that authenticated user? Using HTTP I can use cookies to track session.

Comment: By checking the `HttpSession,` the `remoteUser`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`SipApplicationSession` is for joining two (or more) `SipSession` in order to create a back-to-back UA.

I need to do something similar and I'm working on implementing it this way.
The biggest issue is how to associate a `SipSession` with a `HttpSession`. If you've done this you can simply get the authenticated user of a `SipSession` from the associated `HttpSession`.

For this I will send an extra header in the SIP messages, let's call it `SESSIONID` and the value will be `httpSession.getId()'. Then when processing the SIP message, you can scan through the HTTP sessions and associate the SIP session with the one with the corresponding id.